# SSH CA sign catch-all username

Tags: ssh, certificate-authority

I have a private SSH CA that manages my servers (well I have quite a few of them). All my servers are configured to trust this CA in this way:

```
TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/iBug-CA.pub
```

These servers run a variety of OS's and have different usernames (like `root`, `ubuntu`, `debian`, `admin`, `ibug` etc.). I have a "central" server that I'd like to grant access to an arbitrary username on an arbitrary server, so I signed its user key with this command.

```
ssh-keygen -s ibug_ca.pem -I iBug-Central -n \* id_rsa.pub
```

But the signed certificate (`id_rsa-cert.pub`) can't log in any server, so I had to sign another certificate like this

```
ssh-keygen -s ibug_ca.pem -I iBug-Central -n root,ubuntu,debian,ibug,admin id_rsa.pub
```

The new `id_rsa-cert.pub` can log in to any server with one of the listed usernames, but it can't log in with an unlisted username (e.g. `adm`).

Is there a way to sign a certificate for a catch-all name? I tried omitting the `-n` option of `ssh-keygen` and it didn't work, either.